# Is there a way to automatically/programatically set the HDR brightness in Windows 10 through Task Scheduler or something similar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, brightness, hdr

I'm asking this question in order to automate a workaround for a bug in Windows HDR implementation, where the HDR brightness setting will change to its minimum value when switching users in Windows. (See [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/hdr-keeps-turning-off-when-switching-between-users-on-windows-10.3664556/) for an example of someone else having this issue.)

I'm not looking to fix the bug itself, as that will probably only happen with a future Windows update. However, a workaround I've been using is to go into Windows HDR settings and just clicking on the HDR brightness setting slider (the slider itself stays at the previously set level when the bug happens; clicking on it seems to force the system to remember what the actual setting was, and the brightness instantly changes to what it should be). It should be noted that changing other display settings (e.g., UI scaling, resolution, etc) accomplishes the same thing, but the HDR brightness slider is the easiest to use for this purpose as it doesn't change anything else except the brightness problem itself.

So my question is, is there a way to automatically force an HDR brightness setting (or possibly one of the other display settings) to "change" upon any user login or unlock, either through task scheduler or some other method? Of course, I don't want the setting to actually change, I just want the display to "refresh" in whatever way changing these settings manually is already.